# Why JPA update entity causes stackoverflow？

Tags: jpa

I have an entity Task with id. Tasks belongs to Config. I need to update Task with it's Config doesn't change. Here is my code:
Task:

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Task{

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "config_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Config config;
    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="task_id")
    private Set<ActivityItemTask> activityItemTasks = new HashSet<>();

}
```

```java
@Entity
public class ActivityItemTask {

    private Double score;
    @EmbeddedId
    private ActivityItemTaskId activityItemTaskId;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Embeddable
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class ActivityItemTaskId implements Serializable {
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "activity_item_id")
        private ActivityItem activityItem;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "task_id")
        private Task task;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "config_id")
        private TaskConfig config;

    }
}
```

Config:

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Config{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "config")
    private Set<Task> tasks = new HashSet<>();
}
```

TaskService:

```java
@Service
public class TaskService{
  @Resource
  TaskRepository taskRepository;

 @Transactional
 public Long save(Taskdto dto){
        Config config = new Config();
        config.setId(task.getConfigId());
        s.setTaskConfig(config);
        return taskRepository.save(s).getId();
 }
}
```

TaskDto:

```java
@Data
public class TaskDto {
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    private Long configId;
    private String name;
    private Date beginDate;
    private Date endDate;
    private String note;
}
```

when TaskService#save was called , it throw StackOverflowException:

```java
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

the log shows that my application querys task record and querys task's config and config's tasks and so on.

I am wondering what's wrong with my association annation. Any advice are appreciated.

---

I'm sorry.I have written another 2 calss so that I can find out the truth. It turns out my third calss `ActivityItemTask` may be the root cause. I think `Task. activityItemTasks`  may should be annnotation with `mappedBy=?` But which field should be writtern here?

Comment: Seems to be reported under https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/14641 -- adding ```@Transient``` on ```@OneToMany```. However I can't provide the reason why this happens.

Comment: can you add your complete entity classes?

Comment: @Transient doesn't any sense, It does avoid StackOverflow, But  when I query my config, config.getTasks() always empty.

Comment: please share your complete classes, otherwise its hard to reproduce your problem

Comment: I am sorry, it seems I forget the most important class, I have added it.

Comment: your config class does not even define an Id  - please provide a complete and minimum working sample which reproduces the problem, otherwise it will not be possible to find the cause

Answer (score 0):

I did config wrong association.
`Task` should be :

```java
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "activityItemTaskId.task")
//    @JoinColumn(name = "task_id")
    private Set<ActivityItemTask> activityItemTasks = new HashSet<>();
```

This is how to use `mappedBy` annotation with embedable class.

Thank all you guys commented or answered. You did help me find it out.